# how to print values of specific coordinates in Numpy

Tags: python

I have a numpy array which is a larger version of this

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

np.ndarray(shape=(56,43), dtype=float, order='F')

array([[00, 10]
       [20, 30]])
```

how would I print the value of coordinates (1, 2) of the array so the output would be 20?

Thanks

Comment: @Fabricator: Close, you need to flip the x and y though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip and subtract one from `x` and `y`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[00, 10],
            [20, 30]])

x,y = 1,2

print arr[y-1,x-1] #Gives 20.
```